# Hide TOC at the start of a single section while keeping section numbers

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

I usually use the following to show a table of contents at the beginning of each section :

```
 \AtBeginSection[]{%
 \begin{frame}
     \tableofcontents[currentsection, subsectionstyle=show/show/hide]
 \end{frame}
 }
```

So if I use `\section*{title}`, then there is no table of contents at the beginning of that section. However, I would like the section title to appear in the TOC and I would like the section to be numbered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can temporarily switch of the automatic toc at the begin of a section:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

 \AtBeginSection[]{%
 \begin{frame}
     \tableofcontents[currentsection, subsectionstyle=show/show/hide]
 \end{frame}
 }
\begin{document}

\section{section with toc}
\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}

{
\AtBeginSection[]{}
\section{section withou toc}
\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}
}

\section{section with toc}
\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```